# update table column using values from another table column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've got two tables that look like this

```
TABLE_1
option_id PK,
condition_id FK,
```

And I has another table that looks like this

```
TABLE_2
option_id PK, FK -> TABLE_1
condition_id PK, FK
```

I want to set `condition_id` in TABLE_1 with corresponding values for `condition_id` from TABLE_2.

My script looks like this

```
UPDATE TABLE_1
SET 
    condition_id = t2.condition_id
FROM TABLE_1 t1
INNER JOIN TABLE_2 t2
ON t1.option_id = t2.option_id
```

But it seems to be wrong - after the execution all the values of `condition_id` in `TABLE_1` are the same.

What is wrong?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @mshsayem updated tags with DBMS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is: you are using two instances of `TABLE_1`.

```
UPDATE TABLE_1   <-- first instance

FROM TABLE_1 t1 <-- second instance
```

Thus, while the `FROM` allows you to refer to a combined structure that relates matching entries, this forms a full cross join with the instance of `TABLE_1` that is being updated. To avoid this you would need to add a further condition like `WHERE TU.option_id=t1.option_id`. (I introduced `TU` as an alias for the update target table to avoid ambiguity.)

Or, likely, you might simply use:

```
UPDATE TABLE_1 t1
SET 
    condition_id = t2.condition_id
FROM TABLE_2 t2
WHEREt1.option_id = t2.option_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it :

```
UPDATE table1 
   SET table1.condition_id= table2.condition_id
   FROM table1  INNER JOIN  table2 ON table1.option_id = table2.option_id
```

Comment: but isn't my script the same?